# iOS 5 SDK Create methods that work everywhere

Tags: ios, iphone, methods, ios5

How do you make methods that work across multiple views? For example. I created this:

```
- (void)setPageTitle:(UILabel *)title withText:(NSString *)text
{
    UIColor *pageTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:18.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:118.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    // Set page title
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PassionOne-Regular" size:23];
    [title setFont:font];
    [title setText: text];
    title.textColor = pageTextColor;
    title.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    title.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    CGRect titleRect = [title textRectForBounds:title.bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:999];
    CGRect tr = title.frame;
    tr.size.height = titleRect.size.height;
    title.frame = tr;
}
```

I want to be able to call the setPageTitle method on UILabels within different views. How do I go about doing this? Where do I put this code to make it work? I only want to put it in 1 file and have it work in different views. Thank you.

Comment: Are all *your views* the same custom type ?

Comment: If they all have common custom type, a simple instance method will do it, won't it ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would suggest making this a category on the UIView class.

UIView+PageTitle.h

```
@interface UIView (PageTitle)
- (void)setPageTitle:(UILabel *)title withText:(NSString *)text;
@end
```

UIView+PageTitle.m

```
#import "UIView+PageTitle.h"
@implementation UIView (PageTitle)
- (void)setPageTitle:(UILabel *)title withText:(NSString *)text {
    // your implementation
}
@end
```

Comment: When I call it in my view, should I be doing this: [self setPageTitle:pageTitle withText:@"My text."];

Comment: Yes. Be sure to import the category header for it to work.#import "UIView+PageTitle.h"

Comment: Excellent, it works. I had to change UIView to UIViewController because that is what my files are, but other than that, it worked. Thank you!

Comment: edit *******should I be doing this: [self.view setPageTitle:pageTitle withText:@"My text."];

Answer (score 1):

What you probably are looking for is either you create a subclass of a `UIViewController` (I believe is what you are using) and make it your class `MyUIViewController` with that one as a method, or, you can create a category of the `UIViewController` and add that method. [Here](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) is an explanation on how to create a category, plus some useful info. A category is an extension of the capabilities of a class, pretty much what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocCategories.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH20) you should at least create a useful category. A instance method in a category that doesn't use `self` is misplaced.

Since you are manipulating a `UILabel` you should make that a `UILabel` category.

```
@interface UILabel (PageTitle)
- (void)setPageTitle:(NSString *)text {
    UIColor *pageTextColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:18.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:118.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    // Set page title
    UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PassionOne-Regular" size:23];
    [self setFont:font];
    [self setText: text];
    self.textColor = pageTextColor;
    self.shadowColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    self.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);

    CGRect titleRect = [self textRectForBounds:self.bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:999];
    CGRect tr = self.frame;
    tr.size.height = titleRect.size.height;
    self.frame = tr;
}
@end
```

use it like this:

```
UILabel *myLabel;
[myLabel setPageTitle:@"Foobar"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Add quick way is to add a '+' making it a static method in another class:

UIKitUtilities.h

`+ (void)setPageTitle:(UILabel *)title withText:(NSString *)text;`

And in the m file:

`+ (void)setPageTitle:(UILabel *)title withText:(NSString *)text { ...your code here... }`

Comment: Should I be importing the .h of the file I created within the views that I want to use it in?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  Although the category is better based on your comments.